# DecimalModelBinder price correction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added projection DecimalModelBinder, but i have a problem. entering the product price I enter 10.000,00 but updates to 10000.00 where do i make mistakes. I tried to do examples on the internet but I could not. How can i fix it ? Thank you.

DecimalModelBinder

```
    public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

        object actualValue = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            try
            {
                string value = valueResult.AttemptedValue;

                int decimals = 0;

                while (true)
                {

                    if (value[value.Length - 3] == ',' || value[value.Length - 3] == '.')
                    {
                        decimals = 2;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (value[value.Length - 4] == ',' || value[value.Length - 4] == '.')
                    {
                        decimals = 3;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (value[value.Length - 5] == ',' || value[value.Length - 5] == ',')
                    {
                        decimals = 4;
                        break;
                    }

                    break;
                }

                string final_value;

                final_value = value.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");

                final_value = final_value.Insert(final_value.Length - decimals, ".");

                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(final_value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);

        return actualValue;
```

Comment: surely this is just a case of the format/culture in which you end up displaying the decimal?

Comment: I don't understand, what is the expected output if you input 10.000,00?

Comment: culture  <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" /> i try de-DE but same problem. @Anytoe same price 10.000,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my implementation for a decimal model binder

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            //Check if this is a nullable decimal and a null or empty string has been passed
            var isNullableAndNull = (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType &&
                                      string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue));

            //If not nullable and null then we should try and parse the decimal
            if (!isNullableAndNull)
            {
                actualValue = decimal.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Note the decimal.Parse takes the current culture of the server to parse the number.

Comment: I do not want  to take the culture how I can do it. I do not want the count to change.When I write 10.000.00 I want 10.000.00 in the page that I send

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Are you looking for a currency model binder or a decimal model binder?

Comment: I do not want the number to change. I want it to stay the same when I write 10,000.00 , sorry for bad english.

Comment: Model binding is for posting information to the server.  If you are looking for keeping the format consistent, you need to format your view correctly.  you could annotate your model property with [DataType.Currency] and it will format it with the server culture.  Alternatively you could add a [DisplayFormat] and format it that way.  But I'm still a little confused at what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: @tomclack you realise that actual numbers (as stored in the computer) don't have commas in them? That's just a display format convention used in some countries and cultures. Fran is right (and I was right earlier) , this is a presentational issue. Your binder solves the problem of how to accept strings in that format and parse them as decimals, but internally a decimal doesn't have the comma built in, it's up to you to then decide how to _display_ that value, including, if you wish, the use of commas.